# Overriding methods without falling into infinite recursion

Tags: python, methods, overriding

I want to override a method of the class `dict` in Python, a simple one: `update`. Let's say I want to create a `MyDict` class which is identical to standard `dict` except that it can be updated with `dict`s that have to contain at least 10 elements.

So I would proceed like:

```
def update(self, newdict):
    if len(newdict) <= 10: raise Exception
    self.update(newdict)
```

But in the inner call to `update`, obviously Python calls the overridden function and not the original one. Is there a way to avoid this situations other than simply changing the function names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `update` on the superclass, supplying an instance of the subclass as `self`.

```
def update(self, newdict):
    if len(newdict) <= 10: raise Exception
    dict.update(self, newdict)
```

You can also use [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) to determine the superclass at runtime:

```
def update(self, newdict):
    if len(newdict) <= 10: raise Exception
    super(MyDict, self).update(newdict)
```

In Python 3, you can omit the parameters to `super()`:

```
def update(self, newdict):
    if len(newdict) <= 10: raise Exception
    super().update(newdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you inherit from *dict* class? Use *super* function

```
super(MyDict, self).update
```

should do the trick

Comment: I probably do, but I am too tired :-(